# Step into OpenSSL code using XCode 4.3.2

Tags: xcode, debugging, openssl

I found this project on the internet: https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone.

It has a demo app which calculates MD5 values and takes text input from an editbox. Within the demo app I can step into the OpenSSL code which calculates the MD5 value.

I am using XCode 4.3.2. I have a project which also uses OpenSSL. Within the project something goes wrong with the SSL handshake (this code is executed within OpenSSL).

Though I have built the libraries (libcrypto.a and libssl.a) using the build script from "x2on" and added these libraries to my project I am unable to step into calls to OpenSSL methods from within my own project.

Also I could not discover any relevant setting which is present in the demo app (from "x2on") when I compare the settings with my own app. If I try to step into the OpenSSL call, then execution just moves on to the next line (I do not get into .asm code and also not in the OpenSSL code). Also if I use the right mouse button and choose "Jump to Definition" it brings me to the OpenSSL header file instead of the implementation (.c).

Could somebody give some hints here? How is "stepping into" supposed to work in general? Do the libraries (.a) contains a reference to the location of the source code? Where can you set the search path for source code in XCode? How can you enforce that XCode will re-index the code including the OpenSSL code and make "Jump to Definition" work?

Any help is appreciated as I did discover more people who are or have been struggling with this problem.

ADDITION:
I created a small test app, added libcrypto.a and libssl.a to the Frameworks folder and included the path to the header files for OpenSSL into the Build Settings | Header Search Paths. No problem to step into a piece of OpenSSL code/methods ...
However, when I apply the same strategy to my huge project, then it steps over the OpenSSL call instead of stepping into the OpenSSL call ... I heard that each project should reference a static library only once? If the project references a static library multiple times, then would this break the functionality to step into the code of that library ...?

Forgot to add: for the small test app there was no need to indicate the location of the source files for OpenSSL. So my tentative conclusion is that the .a libs contain a reference to the source files for OpenSSL (how could XCode otherwise know the location of the source files?).

To share some further information: both in my huge project and in the test application it is not possible to jump to the source code by selecting "Jump to Definition". So stepping into the code and "Jump to Definition" seem/are unrelated.

Comment: Are you using same OpenSSL library for your huge project? I think you should be able to step into it. It must be compiled with -g option (generate debug information) for stepping into it.